# How can i update css properties of html objects in external javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am unable to access htmls in object properties in external java script file. How can i access these object properties in js file?

I have my html object defined like:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myJavaScript.js"></script>

<li><a href="#" id="playvideo" onclick="playVideo('watch?v=G2KlPOYu6U8','video1')">How to Install Eclipse and configure Selenium WebDriver</a></li>
<iframe id="video1" class="video iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Following is js script file:

```
function playVideo(strVideoURL,id)
{

    /*document.getElementById('video1').style.visibility=true;
    document.getElementByID('video1').src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2KlPOYu6U8";*/
    alert("Hi"+document.getElementById('video1').currentStyle.display);


}
```

Comment: There is no `currentStyle`. Use `style`. As you have in your commented code.

Comment: the styles i have defined in a separate css file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you you havnt close the header tag. try,

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myJavaScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <li><a href="#" id="playvideo" onclick="playVideo('watch?v=G2KlPOYu6U8','video1')">How to Install Eclipse and configure Selenium WebDriver</a></li>
  <iframe id="video1" class="video iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: the piece of code i posted here is from a different file. there is no pr. with end tags.